# Static library linking failure

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt-creator

My OS is Windows 7 Ultimate, x64. I compiled the library (https://github.com/mfontanini/libtins) with cmake, Visual Studio 12.0. The output was tins.lib. Dependencies: Winpcap, IHPlpapi.lib and WS2_32.lib. Winpcap seemed to work alone, I got all includes at C:\libtins\Include, and all .lib files in C:\libtins except winpcap. The main.cpp source was taken from a library-example. I am unable to understand what's the problem, it seems it fails to read some functions. Compiler for the following source is Qt Creator.

Why does the library fail to link with Qt Creator? Moreover, what's the solution to get this error fixed?

Qt project file is this:

```
QT       += core
QT       -= gui

TARGET = libtins_test
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
INCLUDEPATH += C:/WpdPack/Include
INCLUDEPATH += C:/libtins/Include
LIBS += -LC:/WpdPack/Lib/x64 -lwpcap -lpacket
LIBS += -LC:/libtins -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -ltins
```

main.cpp is this:

```
#include <tins/tins.h>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <QCoreApplication>

using namespace Tins;

class arp_monitor {
public:
    void run(Sniffer &sniffer);
private:
    bool callback(const PDU &pdu);

    std::map<IPv4Address, HWAddress<6>> addresses;
};

void arp_monitor::run(Sniffer &sniffer)
{
    sniffer.sniff_loop(
        std::bind(
            &arp_monitor::callback,
            this,
            std::placeholders::_1
        )
    );
}

bool arp_monitor::callback(const PDU &pdu)
{
    // Retrieve the ARP layer
    const ARP &arp = pdu.rfind_pdu<ARP>();
    // Is it an ARP reply?
    if(arp.opcode() == ARP::REPLY) {
        // Let's check if there's already an entry for this address
        auto iter = addresses.find(arp.sender_ip_addr());
        if(iter == addresses.end()) {
            // We haven't seen this address. Save it.
            addresses.insert({ arp.sender_ip_addr(), arp.sender_hw_addr()});
            std::cout << "[INFO] " << arp.sender_ip_addr() << " is at "
                      << arp.sender_hw_addr() << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            // We've seen this address. If it's not the same HW address, inform it
            if(arp.sender_hw_addr() != iter->second) {
                std::cout << "[WARNING] " << arp.sender_ip_addr() << " is at "
                          << iter->second << " but also at " << arp.sender_hw_addr()
                          << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
        /*
        if(argc != 2) {
            std::cout << "Usage: " << *argv << " <interface>\n";
            return 1;
        }*/
    arp_monitor monitor;
    // Sniffer configuration
    SnifferConfiguration config;
    config.set_promisc_mode(true);
    config.set_filter("arp");

    // Sniff on the provided interface in promiscuous mode
    Sniffer sniffer("eth0", config);

    // Only capture arp packets
    monitor.run(sniffer);
    return a.exec();
}
```

Compile output (Qt Creator):

```
03:13:11: Running steps for project libtins_test...
03:13:11: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
03:13:11: Starting: "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
    C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
    echo 1 /* CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID */ 24 /* RT_MANIFEST */          "debug\\libtins_test.exe.embed.manifest">debug\libtins_test.exe_manifest.rc
if not exist debug\libtins_test.exe if exist debug\libtins_test.exe.embed.manifest del debug\libtins_test.exe.embed.manifest
if exist debug\libtins_test.exe.embed.manifest copy /Y debug\libtins_test.exe.embed.manifest debug\libtins_test.exe_manifest.bak
link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32'     name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df'     language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:debug\libtins_test.exe.embed.manifest     /OUT:debug\libtins_test.exe @C:\Users\burny1\AppData\Local\Temp\libtins_test.exe.3536.47.jom
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl     Tins::IPv4Address::IPv4Address(unsigned int)" (??0IPv4Address@Tins@@QEAA@I@Z) referenced in function     "public: class Tins::IPv4Address __cdecl Tins::ARP::sender_ip_addr(void)const " (?    sender_ip_addr@ARP@Tins@@QEBA?AVIPv4Address@2@XZ)
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct     std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl Tins::operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct     std::char_traits<char> > &,class Tins::IPv4Address const &)" (??6Tins@@YAAEAV?$basic_ostream@DU?    $char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AEAV12@AEBVIPv4Address@0@@Z) referenced in function "private: bool __cdecl     arp_monitor::callback(class Tins::PDU const &)" (?callback@arp_monitor@@AEAA_NAEBVPDU@Tins@@@Z)
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __cdecl     Tins::BaseSniffer::~BaseSniffer(void)" (??1BaseSniffer@Tins@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public:     virtual __cdecl Tins::Sniffer::~Sniffer(void)" (??1Sniffer@Tins@@UEAA@XZ)
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class Tins::PacketWrapper<class     Tins::PDU *,class Tins::Timestamp> __cdecl Tins::BaseSniffer::next_packet(void)" (?    next_packet@BaseSniffer@Tins@@QEAA?AV?$PacketWrapper@PEAVPDU@Tins@@VTimestamp@2@@2@XZ) referenced in     function "private: void __cdecl Tins::SnifferIterator::advance(void)" (?    advance@SnifferIterator@Tins@@AEAAXXZ)
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class Tins::SnifferIterator __cdecl     Tins::BaseSniffer::begin(void)" (?begin@BaseSniffer@Tins@@QEAA?AVSnifferIterator@2@XZ) referenced in     function "public: void __cdecl Tins::BaseSniffer::sniff_loop<class std::_Bind<1,bool,struct     std::_Pmf_wrap<bool (__cdecl arp_monitor::*)(class Tins::PDU const &),bool,class arp_monitor,class     Tins::PDU const &>,class arp_monitor * const,class std::_Ph<1> &> >(class std::_Bind<1,bool,struct     std::_Pmf_wrap<bool (__cdecl arp_monitor::*)(class Tins::PDU const &),bool,class arp_monitor,class     Tins::PDU const &>,class arp_monitor * const,class std::_Ph<1> &>,unsigned int)" (??$sniff_loop@V?    $_Bind@$00_NU?$_Pmf_wrap@P8arp_monitor@@EAA_NAEBVPDU@Tins@@@Z_NV1@AEBV23@@std@@QEAVarp_monitor@@AEAV?    $_Ph@$00@2@@std@@@BaseSniffer@Tins@@QEAAXV?$_Bind@$00_NU?    $_Pmf_wrap@P8arp_monitor@@EAA_NAEBVPDU@Tins@@@Z_NV1@AEBV23@@std@@QEAVarp_monitor@@AEAV?    $_Ph@$00@2@@std@@I@Z)
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class Tins::SnifferIterator __cdecl     Tins::BaseSniffer::end(void)" (?end@BaseSniffer@Tins@@QEAA?AVSnifferIterator@2@XZ) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl Tins::BaseSniffer::sniff_loop<class std::_Bind<1,bool,struct std::_Pmf_wrap<bool (__cdecl arp_monitor::*)(class Tins::PDU const &),bool,class arp_monitor,class Tins::PDU const &>,class arp_monitor * const,class std::_Ph<1> &> >(class std::_Bind<1,bool,struct std::_Pmf_wrap<bool (__cdecl arp_monitor::*)(class Tins::PDU const &),bool,class arp_monitor,class Tins::PDU const &>,class arp_monitor * const,class std::_Ph<1> &>,unsigned int)" (??$sniff_loop@V?    $_Bind@$00_NU?$_Pmf_wrap@P8arp_monitor@@EAA_NAEBVPDU@Tins@@@Z_NV1@AEBV23@@std@@QEAVarp_monitor@@AEAV?    $_Ph@$00@2@@std@@@BaseSniffer@Tins@@QEAAXV?$_Bind@$00_NU?    $_Pmf_wrap@P8arp_monitor@@EAA_NAEBVPDU@Tins@@@Z_NV1@AEBV23@@std@@QEAVarp_monitor@@AEAV?    $_Ph@$00@2@@std@@I@Z)
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl Tins::Sniffer::Sniffer(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class Tins::SnifferConfiguration const &)" (??0Sniffer@Tins@@QEAA@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AEBVSnifferConfiguration@1@@Z) referenced in function main
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl     Tins::SnifferConfiguration::SnifferConfiguration(void)" (??0SnifferConfiguration@Tins@@QEAA@XZ)     referenced in function main
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl     Tins::SnifferConfiguration::set_promisc_mode(bool)" (?    set_promisc_mode@SnifferConfiguration@Tins@@QEAAX_N@Z) referenced in function main
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl     Tins::SnifferConfiguration::set_filter(class std::basic_string<char,struct     std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?    set_filter@SnifferConfiguration@Tins@@QEAAXAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?    $allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function main
debug\libtins_test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 10 unresolved externals
jom: C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\build-libtins_test-Desktop_Qt_5_3_MSVC2013_64bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug     [debug\libtins_test.exe] Error 1120
jom: C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\build-libtins_test-Desktop_Qt_5_3_MSVC2013_64bit-Debug\Makefile         [debug] Error 2
03:13:12: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project libtins_test (kit: Desktop Qt 5.3 MSVC2013 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
03:13:12: Elapsed time: 00:01.
```

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: The error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol at the compile output.

Comment: Questions usually end in question marks. For example, "What is your question?"

Comment: Why does the library fail to link with Qt Creator? Moreover, what's the solution to get this error fixed? ~ Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Including the libraries using -L and -l notations has never worked for me using the MSVC compiler. I have no idea why though. Try including the libraries with full paths including the extensions. For ex.

```
LIBS += C:/WpdPack/Lib/x64/wpcap.lib \
        C:/WpdPack/Lib/x64/packet.lib \
        C:/libtins/ws2_32.lib \
        C:/libtins/iphlpapi.lib \
        C:/libtins/tins.lib
```

Even the order in which you include these libraries will matter in the case of MSVC. If one library is dependent on the other library, the top level library has to be on the top. i.e. if A.lib is dependent on B.lib, you have to add A first followed by B.

Comment: Yes I did, I also tried quoting those paths. Different order attempted as well.

Comment: I found a new error by trying this:

LIBS += -LC:/WpdPack/Lib/x64/wpcap.lib -lwpcap
LIBS += -LC:/WpdPack/Lib/x64/Packet.lib -lpacket
LIBS += -LC:/libtins/WS2_32.lib -lws2_32
LIBS += -LC:/libtins/IPHlpapi.lib -liphlpapi
LIBS += -LC:/libtins/tins.lib -ltins

error: LNK1104: cannot open file 'wpcap.lib'
thing which is invalid because I navigated to the specific folder and the file exists, it's there.

Answer (score 0):

This is because x64 libs set is incomplete in WpdPack. You can try 32bit or build x64 bit ownself.